# Jsp attribute names

Tags: jsp

Is there a way to use jsp expressions to dynamically name elements like this:

```
<% for (int x = 0; x < 5; x ++) {%>

<div id ='<%=x%>' name = '<%=x%>'>

//some data

</div>

<%}%>
```

I am getting unterminated tag compile error on `<%=x%>`. What can be a solution/workaround for this?

Thanks very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jsp attribute value-trying to use expressions to form attribute values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858478/jsp-attribute-value-trying-to-use-expressions-to-form-attribute-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd place some whitespaces - `<%= x %>`